# Grep command with multiple patterns

Tags: linux, grep

Hi i am currently use this to grep:

```
$ grep -nri --exclude-dir=DELIVERY_REL "xxxxxx\.h" --colour --include=*.{c,h}
```

I am trying to fine tune the search results of my grep to include multiple patterns. I have tried multiple ways recommended on stack-overflow on similar questions, but to no avail. What i need to grep:

```
xxxxxx.h and #include or xxxxxx.h and # include (with a space)
```

Answer (score 2):

To include multiple pattern to *grep* command you need option "**-e**".

For example you can include pattern "pattern1" e "pattern2" in this way:

```
grep -e "pattern1" -e "pattern2" filename.ext
```

Answer (score 1):

**OR:** To search for lines that match regex `A` *or* `B` specify each of the regexes with a preceding `-e` option in a single `grep` command: `grep -e A -e B`.
Alternatively, use the alternation operator inside a single regex: `grep -E 'A|B'`

**AND:** To print only lines that match regex `A` *and* `B` chain two `grep` searches: `grep A | grep B`.
Alternatively, list all possible orders in which the regex can match in a single regex: `grep -E 'A.*B|B.*A'`

For your specific case you could use

```
grep 'xxxxxx\.h' | grep -E '# ?include'
```

Here the `?` after the space means that the space is optional.
`# ?include` is equivalent to `#include|# include`.

Answer (score 0):

I managed it with the following command:

```
grep -nri --include=*.{c,h} --exclude-dir=DELIVERY_REL "xxxxxx\.h" | grep ":#include\|:# include"
```

Comment: Um, isn't this the answer I gave you? I would be happy if you could at least upvote my answer if it helped you. Answering (your own question) with an answer from someone other is kinda rude.

Comment: Sorry i have miss out, i'm out of office over the weekends